# Stacks in Assembly and how to use them efficiently

Tags: assembly, x86, stack, callstack

I have this message:

```
msg: .ascii "March was an awkward month"
```

And I need to invert every word after every `blank space`.
For example, the final result should be:

```
month awkward an was March
```

I'm using a virtual machine (Oracle VM VirtualBox), and I'm required to use stacks to make this work. I've tried looking for information almost everyewhere, including the slides my professor gave me. But I still can't figure out how they work or how would aplly to this situation. Would really appreciate some help.

Comment: Let's say the problem was simpler: reverse all the letters in the whole phrase, i.e. to get `htnom drawkwa na saw hcraM`.  Can you figure out how to do that, using a stack?

Comment: (Also, March was a little more than awkward...)

Comment: Thinking about it, I would try to do a for so I can go trough the whole sentence, register one character and then push. After that I would've have to pop every character in reverse order I think, but I can't think of a way to do that. I'm pretty new to all of this, I'm a first year in computer sciences and Assembly is a really weird language, so excuse me for the lack of knowledge.

Comment: (And agree with that statement).

Comment: if you push `M` push `a` push `r` and then pop pop pop you'll get `r`, `a`, `M`.

Comment: I woul've have to pop the `r` first then

Comment: I don't quite get what you mean.  When you do the first pop, you'll get back what was last pushed, which in my example is `r`.  A stack is a first-in last-out or last-in first-out depending on you want to look at it.

Comment: So the solution would be to start pushing from the end of the sentence? And then popping?

Comment: Let's say that the string you want to reverse is "Mar".  First, push M, then push a, then r.  Then pop 3 times, and you'll get r, a, M -- in that order.

Comment: A stack is a last-in first-out data structure.  It is this property that you're supposed to use to accomplish the reversal of letters.  So, the idea is to stack the whole string.  There is an initial phase where you push each letter of the string, then a second phase where you pop every element that you pushed.  The letters of the string will come off the stack in reverse order of how they were stacked.

Comment: So, since I don't want to reverse the letters and only the words, I need to find a way to save each word by identifying the `blank space`, and push them from the last word (it being "month") and pop them back out. At least that's how I'm beggining to think about the problem.

Comment: Look at what happens when you reverse all the letters.  The words are reversed!  But individually the words have their letters backwards.  If only there was a way to reverse things!

Comment: Oh god, this makes sense, I'll have to think about this :)

Comment: There's always multiple ways to do things.  You can use one stack, or use more than one stack.  You can stack letters or you can stack pointers.  The point being that when you stack some things, as they de-stack they come back reversed from the stacking.

Answer (score 1):

There are "stacks" (general data structures, FILO buffers), and for assembly language there is "the stack" (the one maintained to keep track of calls and returns, often with assistance from the CPU in the form of PUSH/POP instructions and special "stack pointer" register).

You can solve this problem using "the stack" alone. Specifically; you'd have a recursive function that searches for the start of the next word then (if a next word is found) calls itself with a pointer to the remainder of the string (starting at the next word), then prints its first word alone.

> I'm required to use stacks

Is this the wording that your professor/instructor used? If they said "stacks" (plural, meaning more than one stack) then it doesn't make sense. If they said "you're required to use the stack" then see my comments above.

If they said "you're required to implement your own stack data structure and use it" then it becomes similar, but replacing recursion with loops and explicit pushes/pops. Specifically; "while end of string not reached { find start of next word; push start and length of first word};" and then "while stack not empty { pop start and length of word; print word; }").

Comment: Thank you, this helped me understand more about stacks. Sorry if I used the plural form of the word. The objetive is to use a single stack. Thanks for explaining and to Erik Eidt for being pacient and make me visualize what happens. I'll update you when I submit the exercise. Thank you for the help.

Comment: We can also use the runtime call stack without recursion, of course.